# Add method for all controllers Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, action, controllers

I have a layout where the footer is common for all sections. That footer has to make different methods but I do not know how to implement in all controllers at once.

I thought I could implement the constructor in the `BaseController`, but I think that is a bad idea.

Comment: create a new controller class that extends BaseController and extend your controllers from it, that way it will be implemented in all controllers at once and you can even override it

Comment: What do you mean that footer has to make different methods.

Comment: made the intention a little clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do this... you're simply extending `BaseController` and calling it `BadassController`, then extending that in your controllers.

```
class BadassController extends BaseController {}
```

Comment: Updated post with the general gist of what the link had, sorry. This is a L4 post btw, so you should look into L5.